# Why won't SuperSearch look in Matrix field to find results?

Tags: matrix, solspace, supersearch

I am trying to figure out why my technology channel won't return any results when using keywords contained in a wygwam text field within a matrix row.  The search yields results for this section when keywords are the title of the entry, so channel is set correctly and I am receiving results.  If I search a term not contained in the title, but within the matrix field I get results from other channels, but not from my technology channel.

**Versions**

- EE 2.9.0
- SuperSearch 2.2.2
- Matrix 2.6

**Search template**

```
<form method="get" action="{path=search/results/search}">
     <input type="text" name="keywords" id="keywords" placeholder="Search">
     <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

**Result template**

```
{exp:super_search:results channel="technology_update"}
        ...output content here...
{/exp:super_search:results}
```

**Matrix field**

`{technology_rd}` is my matrix field.  Which has `Is field searchable?` set to `Yes` as well as the `Is col searchable?` checkbox selected for the wygwam textbox in the matrix row.

I recently updated the module form 2.1.4 to 2.2.2 as I noticed a number of Matrix related improvements in the the changelog to no avail.  Any ideas what I could be missing here? Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks!

Comment: What about Matrix module version? It should be possible to search Matrix fields if your version is at least 2.5

Comment: @Milksamsa I edited above to include my matrix version - its 2.6

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Was the field and Matrix columns set to "searchable" ***after*** creating entries with Matrix content? If so, that data might not yet be in the `exp_channel_data` database table, in which Super Search searches. Re-saving the entries would populate `exp_channel_data` with searchable Matrix content, and Super Search should then be able to detect the entry.

Comment: Yes, I set the searchable after as you described and saving again fixed the issue, thanks!!